# Cannot get Session value in another action in asp.net core 6.0

Tags: asp.net-core, session, asp.net-core-6.0

Here is my setting:

```
//...

       services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();         
            services.AddSession(options => { 
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
            });     

//....
        app.UseRouting(); 
        app.UseCookiePolicy();
        app.UseSession();
//....
```

And here is the controller code:

```
    [Route("get-captcha")]
    [HttpGet] 
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(FileStreamResult), (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
    public IActionResult GetCaptcha() {
          HttpContext.Session.SetString("xxx", "123"); 
//....
    }

  

        [Route("login")]
        [HttpPost] 
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(UserAuth), (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
        public IActionResult Login(Login login) { 
                string vv =  HttpContext.Session.GetString("xxx"); 
                //.....
        }
```

Comment: I have test your sample code, it works well on myside, pls set break point and debug it, show us the error message.

Comment: @JasonPan, this is no error message, the key of the problem is that i cannot get the value in session in Login action, the parmeter 'vv' is null.

Comment: @JasonPan Can you give me your example with all setting code? and do you use .net core 6.0 ？

Comment: Yes, I use .net 6. And I also use your sample code.

Comment: @JasonPan I mean you can post your all start up setting , and i will compare my code with yours, because my setting is too much, maybe i add other setting which cause my problem, thanks in advance!

Comment: Please set break point after setstring method, [like my pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXUKH.png). I want make you have set session successfully in GetCaptcha method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242100/discussion-between-jason-pan-and-louraq).